# I can see the number of up and down votes on SO, but not on MSO, SF and SU :(

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, down-votes, up-votes

I have found this:

## SO

[your browser's image loading sucks http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/8362/schermafbeelding2010050.png](http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/8362/schermafbeelding2010050.png)

## Meta SO

[your browser's image loading sucks http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/2503/schermafbeelding2010050f.png](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/2503/schermafbeelding2010050f.png)

Can't someone just make it that this also works on Meta? And SuperUser and ServerFault? It's a trilogy/quadrilogy, right? They should all have the same features. Not that anyone ever uses this feature, but... well, you know, I am a perfectionist.

Comment: It's not my browser's image loading, it's the fact that you posted images from ImageShack. ;)

Comment: Oh hehe. I ALWAYS use THAT alt-text on `/M?S[O|F|U]/i` :)        .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rep for "view vote count" privilege should be lower (on meta)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-lower-on-meta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ability that you get only when you've accumulated [1000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: kthx didn't know hehe

Answer (score 0):

You only get this ability when you have 1,000 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You need 1000 reputation to view the breakdowns. You have over 1k rep on StackOverflow, but only 185 on MSO.