# Privilege page, tracker, and notifications still indicate that 1,000 reputation is required to see vote counts here, even though it was lowered to 100

Tags: bug, status-declined, meta, privileges, help-center

Just today, the system was [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379767/377214) so that only 100 reputation is required to view vote counts here on Meta Stack Exchange.

However, the privilege pages [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) still continue to indicate that 1,000 reputation is required to gain the privilege.

As far as I can tell, the privilege tracker in the user profile as well as the privilege notification system also use the same system to show how far a user is from earning a privilege. The former also still likely indicates that the user needs 1,000 reputation: it will show as progress to 1,000, but once the user completes it, it won't affect anything as the user already had the ability. The latter is effectively a meaningless notification.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Technically it's 1,000 reputation to receive the established user privilege, which happened to be the same threshold as viewing vote counts. That privilege is tied to some other things in the system and not *only* viewing vote counts, so I don't know if it's feasible to change the reputation threshold for the privilege too.

Comment: @animuson Those are not mentioned in the help center. The page only mentions the privilege to view vote counts. It should be updated to say 100 rep and the other things tied to it should be detached from it. Alternatively, it might just be best to make those alternative things be also adjusted to 100.

Comment: By the way, what are those other things exactly?

Comment: They are mostly behind-the-scenes things that affect accounts at that reputation threshold, which is why they are not mentioned there. Detaching them is a significant amount of additional effort versus changing a reputation threshold in a site setting when it only affects one site on the network. It's possible we'd be able to change the privilege threshold and live with the oddities. Like I said, I don't know what all it affects. But if we can't, the likelier solution is just living with the privilege being weird here.

Comment: @animuson I think changing those other internal things to also be given at 100 reputation is the most technically feasible solution here. If you don't do anything, you can cue questions from users as to why they're being notified of a privilege they already had for a long time, and having to repeatedly explain that the notification wasn't adjusted because of certain internal things mentioned nowhere on the page.

Comment: Should the "see vote counts" privilege be its own section in the help center, like how "vote down", "edit community wiki", and "create chat rooms" are (each at 100 rep), and "see vote counts" be removed from the "established user" description?

Comment: @Sonic The notification issue would be easy to prevent by just setting this particular privilege to not notify at all on this site, which is already an available setting. It currently only notifies non-veterans anyways.

Comment: @animuson Sure, but that still leaves the issue of the privilege tracker on the user profile.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While we can make changes to what reputation is required for specific privileges, the components of each privilege can't be broken up or edited in a custom/per-site way and we don't have any plans to allow for this. As animuson commented, there are also other internal things attached to this privilege that are not mentioned in the help center and the privilege tracker.

We made the decision to allow everyone with 100 reputation here to see vote splits because those people often have that ability on their primary sites and they benefit from being able to see them here without us requiring them to have actually participated here.

So, our options here are to roll back that change (and force everyone to have 1,000 reputation to see vote splits again) or to leave it as-is and consider this a "secret" perk for people. We do not want the other internal things attached to that privilege to be given out at only 100 reputation, and we feel the value of seeing the vote splits is outweighed by the slight confusion that some might experience at the help center pages and privilege tracker on the user profile being incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

Agreed, in my profile it is showing my next privilege is "view vote counts" at 1k reputation even though it is at 100 reputation.

I recommend the following as well, but it might not be accepted well:

- Combine the established user achievement with [Create gallery chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms). So now the title is "Established user", with the description of "Create gallery rooms".
- Remove the [View vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) and put it at the 100 reputation. It should also have the "View vote counts" as the title.

Comment: What value does this add?